# Uninitialized constant Spree::User after creating attributes in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I added two attributes to my model:

```
#group.rb

class Spree::Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end

#user_decorator.rb
Spree::User.class_eval do
  belongs_to :group, class_name: "Spree::Group"
end
```

I created a new spree folder in my models directory and created a file for group.rb and user_decorator.rb and added the code then ran:

```
bundle exec rake:db migrate
```

I then recived this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::User
```

I'm unsure of how to fix this error and wonder if it is because I just added the attributes to my model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your files inside `app/models/spree/`